# Primarily opinion based question with exact duplicate - close as duplicate or not

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

What is proper way to close exact duplicate of primarily opinion based question?

Do you vote to close "As Duplicate" (that is also on its way to closure) or just close vote as "Primarily Opinion Based", or it doesn't really matter either way?

Example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892018/hibernate-stored-procedure-pros-and-cons

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882083/using-hibernate-with-store-procedure

Comment: If you do the Googling for them now then they'll come back and expect you do it again next time.  Don't feed the vampires.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: When you close as duplicate then you solved their problem.  Off topic questions should not get a solution, they should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for explanation. Actually, my first instinct was to close as off-topic, but since I just ran out of close votes I though I might ask here for more insights.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither is really *wrong*.  If you have a relevant gold badge you might want to close as a duplicate as you can avoid the need for 4 other people to also vote.  That said, I personally prefer to close duplicate question that also merit closure for another reason for *that other reason* because it makes it much more apparent to the author and any future readers that the type of question just isn't welcome (at least in the form its in) rather than having them go to a duplicate in the hopes of finding or posting an answer only to see that the question indeed isn't something that belongs here.

Answer (score 4):

Since "Primarily Opinion Based" is itself an opinion, it's always better to close as a more 'objective' reason when you can; if for no other reason than it's harder to subjectively say something isn't a duplicate than it is to say it isn't opinion based.

Close the second as a duplicate of the first, and the first should be closed as "Primarily opinion based".

Answer (score 2):

For good reasons, policy (official and community) is cautious about deleting duplicates. So a crap question that is also a duplicate is less likely to be deleted than an otherwise equivalent crap. So I tend not to vote to close craps questions as duplicates, but use one of the other applicable close reasons.